# PyUnit with child processes

Tags: python, python-unittest, child-process

In some Python code, I `fork` and do some processing in a child process while the parent waits for it to exit. It doesn't `exec` after the `fork`.

I'm having a problem testing this code in PyUnit, because when the child process exits explicitly with `sys.exit`, it creates a PyUnit error.

This code below produces the problem

```
class TestClass(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            os.waitpid(pid,0)
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in test
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Is there some way to avoid PyUnit failing the test if a child process exits explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that sys.exit does is throw a SystemExit exception, that bubbles up as normal.  However os._exit(0) will exit immediately and does not give any cleanup code a chance to run.  This prevents PyUnit from doing anything, including failing the test.  So in your test code you can trap SystemExit and call os._exit instead.

If the child process expects some explicit cleanup to happen on exit, you'll have to arrange to do that in your test case.